# Display Snackbar without CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, snackbar

I have Displayed Snackbar using CoordinatorLayout but in some layout i did't used CoordinatorLayout layout and i want to display snackbar but faced problem with it.

I have tried following way to achieve snackbar without CoordinatorLayout but it will display following result.

```
Snackbar.make(getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView(), "Testing Snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

[image]

Test it with android 8.0 Oreo

Is there any way to achieve Snackbar without CoordinatorLayout?

Thanks in advance.

code

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

RelativeLayout rootView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);

        Log.e("onCreateView", "onCreateView");

        rootView = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.rootView);
        setSnackBar(rootView, "Testing with answered");
        return view;
    }

public static void setSnackBar(View coordinatorLayout, String snackTitle) {
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, snackTitle, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
        snackbar.show();
        View view = snackbar.getView();
        TextView txtv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
        txtv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
public static void setSnackBar(View root, String snackTitle) {
  Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(root, snackTitle, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
  snackbar.show();
  View view = snackbar.getView();
  TextView txtv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
  txtv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
}
```

Just call the above method and pass any parent layout such as `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout` or `ScrollView`, for example:

```
setSnackBar(layout,"This is your SnackBar");  //here "layout" is your parentView in a layout
```

Do not forget to find your view using `findViewById()`.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer 
I have tried but it will give following error 
No suitable parent found from the given view. Please provide a valid view.

Comment: @NileshPanchal in my case it is working for any view, I have just put this code in my Utils class and called this method, and it's working like charm

Comment: @NileshPanchal have you provide and findyour parent view with id??

Comment: Hello @Shashwat Gupta It is working fine with Activity but not with Fragment and i want in Fragment.
No Worry i have accepted your answer may it will help for other thanks for the answer.

Comment: I haven't tried it in fragment if you want it in fragment just put this method in activity and call it from fragment

Comment: It's working fine with calling from Fragment to Activity method  Thanks again bro.

Answer (score 25):

Try this easy piece of code.. a dummy view from the android framework itself is used

`Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),"Your Text Here",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: I was trying to show a snackbar inside an adapter class, this worked perfectly since all I passed to my adapter is Context.

Comment: perfect idea thanx

Comment: It can basically work with any view as far as I know so here the snackbar is  given a view from the android framework itself which works properly.

Comment: You deserve a medal !

Comment: This is crashing the app. android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39 in com.webrich.ssatrclite:layout/design_layout_snackbar_include: Binary XML file line #39 in com.webrich.ssatrclite:layout/design_layout_snackbar_include: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39 in com.webrich.ssatrclite:layout/design_layout_snackbar_include: Error inflating class <unknown>

Answer (score 2):

As others suggest best solution to do this is via method mentioned before. I would add and option to show SnackBar with button to dismiss SnackBar. This comes useful when you'd like to give user time to read your message and then acknowledge your application that your user read your message.

```
   public void setSnackBar(View root, String textToDisplay) {
    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(root, textToDisplay, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
    snackbar.setAction("OK", new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            snackbar.dismiss();
            //your other action after user hit the "OK" button
        }
    });
    snackbar.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

use this **view** instance of **CoordinatorLayout**:

```
View view = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "your text", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
snackbar.show();
```

Comment: any difference from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48192738/5049244 ?